# How to serve JS/CSS/Images from CDN in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I was wondering how I can set up a CDN to serve static assets - JS/CSS/Image files of Moodle. Is there any plugin that can help? Or would I need to write it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to achieve it:

1. setup a global CDN variable and prepend it
2. define cdnURL variable at both the PHP level and JavaScript level
3. I keep all JavaScript, CSS, JQuery, images in a separate folder and use/link it inside my custom plugins or core Moodle files.